# Eclipse plug-in not working when deployed

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I have written an Eclipse plug-in that works fine when it's being run in the development runtime, however after creating an update site and installing, the behavior changes.

For the most part the functionality does work, it just appears unable to display 2 dialog boxes. The first is a popup dialog subclassed from org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.PopupDialog. The second has been subclassed from org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.

The rest of the code around these dialogs appears to run as if they're not there at all so I'm thinking there is a difference between the two environments (the development runtime and the installed runtime) that is preventing the plugin from finding the correct classes/displaying them properly.

I have tried adding the org.eclipse.jface.dialogs package to the plugin manifest, however I cannot find the exact package that I have imported into the code. I can import org.eclipse.jface.databinding.dialog, but it's not the same package obviously. I can however add org.eclipse.jface as a dependency to the feature.xml for the plugin. This apparently has no affect on my problem.

As it works as expected in development and I can't find any error messages, I don't know what to do next. Can anyone suggest where I might be going wrong?

Adam

* More info as requested ***
When developing I am running the plugin as an Eclipse application. I then built my update site and installed it into my RTC version of Eclipse. It was at this point it stopped working.

When the plugin is installed into Eclipse it is definitely started. I have confirmed this from the OSGi console and also from running it. The code around the dialogs executes ok. In context I have a class that does some XML processing, displays a dialog that allows the user to change a few variables and then processing continues. In the installed version of the plugin, the code runs start-finish using the default values, that is, not showing my dialog box.

In the Manifest.MF of my plugin I tried adding the org.eclipse.jface plugin to the dependencies tab, but it didn't seem to fix the problem.

I'm not sure about the Eclipse error log. I wasn't sure where to find this.

The manifest for my plugin:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: RTC Scripter
Bundle-SymbolicName: RTC_Scripter;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 2.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.ibm.cics.dev.rtcscripter.Activator
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.6.2";visibility:=reexport,
 org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 com.ibm.team.concert;bundle-version="3.0.0",
 com.ibm.team.log4j.ui;bundle-version="1.1.0",
 com.ibm.team.process.client;bundle-version="1.2.0",
 com.ibm.team.process.common;bundle-version="1.2.0",
 com.ibm.team.repository.client;bundle-version="1.1.0",
 com.ibm.team.repository.common;bundle-version="1.1.0",
 com.ibm.team.repository.common.json;bundle-version="1.1.0",
 com.ibm.team.repository.common.remoteaccess;bundle-version="1.1.0",
 com.ibm.team.repository.common.remoteaccess.auth;bundle-version="1.1.0",
 com.ibm.team.repository.common.serialize;bundle-version="1.1.0",
 com.ibm.team.repository.common.transport;bundle-version="1.1.0",
 com.ibm.team.rtc.common;bundle-version="3.0.0",
 com.ibm.team.rtc.common.scriptengine;bundle-version="2.1.0",
 com.ibm.team.workitem.client;bundle-version="2.2.0",
 com.ibm.team.workitem.common;bundle-version="2.3.0",
 org.eclipse.ui.console;bundle-version="3.5.0",
 com.ibm.team.foundation.client;bundle-version="1.1.0",
 RTC_Scripter_EMF.editor;bundle-version="2.0.0";visibility:=reexport
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Export-Package: com.ibm.cics.dev.rtcscripter.util.export
Import-Package: org.eclipse.core.resources
```

Comment: You need to provide a bit more information. 
Are you running your plug-in as an eclipse application within the workspace? 
When the plug-in is installed into Eclipse can you tell if it is started?
Is there anything in the eclipse error log?
Please post your MANIFEST.MF.
I am not sure what you mean by "I have tried adding the org.eclipse.jface.dialogs package to the plugin manifest,". If your classes import something from this package then you must have this package as an import in your manifest, OR, you must have require bundle for the bundle providing this package.

Comment: Hey Kat. Thanks for your help. I Googled Eclipse error log and found I was producing an NPE. I was doing stuff with the workspace, so in dev, I had a simple one, but in my regular Eclipse it was more complex. Anyway, I found and corrected the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First check the link or plug-in installer about version and what eclipse you are using.
Because there are alot of eclipse so it must be suitable.