# Eclipse Custom Decorator Works in Runtime Environment but not when deployed

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am working on a custom decorator for Eclipse. When I test it in the development runtime environment, the decorator works properly. It shows in the list of available Label Decorators

```
(Windows > Prefences > General > Appearance > Label Decorations)
```

When I deploy the feature, the decorator does not appear in the list of available decorators loaded Eclipse starts.

I have searched on Stack Overflow, I found this article [Eclipse plug-in not working when deployed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222620/eclipse-plug-in-not-working-when-deployed) but it wasn't what I needed.

Thanks for your time and consideration in advance.

Here is my plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <!--define the decorator -->
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.decorators">
      <decorator
         id="com.quickenloans.clutch.decorator"
         label="Packet System Decorator"
         state="true"
         class= "com.quickenloans.clutch.decorator.core.PSLightWeightFileDecorator"
         adaptable="true"
         lightweight="true">

         <enablement>
            <objectClass name="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource"/>      
         </enablement>
         <description>
               Adds decorators to Packet System files that need to be saved back to DEV

        </description>
    </decorator>
</extension>
```

Here is my manifest.mf

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Decorator
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.quickenloans.clutch.decorator;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.quickenloans.clutch.decorator.core.DecoratorActivator
Bundle-Vendor: QUICKENLOANS
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
    org.eclipse.core.runtime,
    org.eclipse.ui.workbench
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Import-Package: com.quickenloans.argonauts.core.preferences,
    org.eclipse.core.resources,
    org.eclipse.ui.texteditor
Export-Package: com.quickenloans.clutch.decorator.constants,
    com.quickenloans.clutch.decorator.core
```

Comment: How are you deploying this?

Comment: Also your plugin is importing `com.quickenloans.argonauts.core.preferences` - have you deployed the plugin containing that as well?

Comment: Hi, I am deploying this as a feature with the com.quickenloans.argonauts.core plugin (which handles the core functionality of the plugin, i.e., connections to servers, all the property pages for the plugin), if i could post a screenshot, i would.

Comment: So did you use 'Export Deployable Features' and then use Install New Software? Note that you will need to increment the version numbers each time you do this to make sure Eclipse knows it is a new version.

Comment: Yes and yes.The qualifier makes it a new version all the time.

Comment: The only other thing I can see is JavaSE-1.7 as the required execution level. Is the Eclipse using Java 7 or 8? Otherwise check the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory for messages.

Comment: I'm using Java 1.7 as the plugin is being developed to extend Eclipse editor shipped with Progress Developer Studio for OpenEdge. As of version 11.6 (PDSOE) Eclipse is locked to 4.3.1 and it includes Java 1.7.

I will look at the .metadata directory for log files.